# Apache HttpClient - Need to use MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I have server which receives requests from clients and based on the requests connects to some external website & does some operations.

I am using Apache Commons `HttpClient` (v 2.0.2) to do these connections (I know it's old, but I have to use it because of other restrictions).

My server is not going to get frequent requests. I think it may be a lot of requests when it's first deployed. Then on it's only going to be a few requests a day. There may be occasional spurts when again there are a lot of requests occasionally.

All connections are going to be one of 3 URLS - they may be http or https

I was thinking of using separate instances of `HttpClient` for each request

Is there any need for me to use a common `HttpClient` object & use it with  `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` for different connections.
How exactly does MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager help - does it keep the connection open even after you call releaseConnection? How long will it keep it open?

All my connections are going to be GET & they are going to return 10-20 bytes at most. I am not downloading anything. The reason I am using `HttpClient` rather than core java libraries is because occasionally, I may want to use HTTP 1.0 (I don't think java classes support this) and I also may want to do Http Redirects automatically.

Comment: Check http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html ,it contains detailed answers for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` in a considerably multi-threaded environment and it works very well.

Here's an implementation of a Client pool:

```
public class HttpClientPool {

    // Single-element enum to implement Singleton.
    private static enum Singleton {

        // Just one of me so constructor will be called once.

        Client;
        // The thread-safe client.
        private final CloseableHttpClient threadSafeClient;
        // The pool monitor.
        private final IdleConnectionMonitor monitor;

        // The constructor creates it - thus late
        private Singleton() {
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            // Increase max total connection to 200
            cm.setMaxTotal(200);
            // Increase default max connection per route to 200
            cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);

            // Make my builder.
            HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                    .setConnectionManager(cm);
            // Build the client.
            threadSafeClient = builder.build();
            // Start up an eviction thread.
            monitor = new IdleConnectionMonitor(cm);
            // Start up the monitor.
            Thread monitorThread = new Thread(monitor);
            monitorThread.setDaemon(true);
            monitorThread.start();
        }

        public CloseableHttpClient get() {
            return threadSafeClient;
        }

    }

    public static CloseableHttpClient getClient() {
        // The thread safe client is held by the singleton.
        return Singleton.Client.get();
    }

    public static void shutdown() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        // Shutdown the monitor.
        Singleton.Client.monitor.shutdown();
    }

    // Watches for stale connections and evicts them.
    private static class IdleConnectionMonitor implements Runnable {

        // The manager to watch.

        private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
        // Use a BlockingQueue to stop everything.
        private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stopSignal = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);

        IdleConnectionMonitor(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm) {
            this.cm = cm;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                // Holds the stop request that stopped the process.
                Stop stopRequest;
                // Every 5 seconds.
                while ((stopRequest = stopSignal.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) == null) {
                    // Close expired connections
                    cm.closeExpiredConnections();
                    // Optionally, close connections that have been idle too long.
                    cm.closeIdleConnections(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                // Acknowledge the stop request.
                stopRequest.stopped();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // terminate
            }
        }

        // Pushed up the queue.
        private static class Stop {

            // The return queue.

            private final BlockingQueue<Stop> stop = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Stop>(1);

            // Called by the process that is being told to stop.
            public void stopped() {
                // Push me back up the queue to indicate we are now stopped.
                stop.add(this);
            }

            // Called by the process requesting the stop.
            public void waitForStopped() throws InterruptedException {
                // Wait until the callee acknowledges that it has stopped.
                stop.take();
            }

        }

        public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            // Signal the stop to the thread.
            Stop stop = new Stop();
            stopSignal.add(stop);
            // Wait for the stop to complete.
            stop.waitForStopped();
            // Close the pool.
            HttpClientPool.getClient().close();
            // Close the connection manager.
            cm.close();
        }

    }

}
```

All you need to do is `CloseableHttpResponse conversation = HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(request);` and when you've finished with it, just `close` it and it will be returned to the pool.

Comment: I am using an old version of HttpClient - I don't think this is even supported. Also, my question is more about whether I really need pooling or management of connections?

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what your SLAs are and if the the performance is within the acceptable/expected response times. Your solution will work without any issues but it is not scalable if your application demands grow over time.

Using `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` is much more elegant/scalable solution than having to manage 3 independent HttpClient objects.

Comment: I am not going to be managing 3 HttpClient objects. My thread function will have only 1 HttpClient object. However more than 1 thread would be running at a time.

Comment: Creating a connection, whether its a db, jms, or http is an expensive operation. In this case, you are creating HttpClient (a connection) every time in this thread function. Or are you saying there is only one HttpClient instance shared across all threads? Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How long will MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager keep the connection open after you call releaseConnection.